# Double transform with delay

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a side-container that I want to appear when a button is clicked. What I would like to do is to first use `translateX` do make it come in from the side, and then when it has moved the distance I want it to, I want it to skew a bit with `skewX`.

However, when I use the CSS when the button is clicked, i.e. when it appears:

```
transform: translateX(0px) skewX(10deg);
transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
```

It does the transforms simultaneously.

I can then get around this by using `right` (it's a fixed element) with the CSS:

```
right: 0;
transform: skewX(10deg);
transition-property: right, transform;
transition-delay: 0.0s, 0.1s;
```

I was just wondering if this could be done with transform alone without the use of `right`, i.e. making a delay between the transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Hey probably not directly, but the same effect can be achieved by nesting elements as the below:

```
HTML

    <div class="main">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>

Css

.main{
  width:200x;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition-duration:.2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
  position:relative;
  }
.content{
  position:absolute;
  
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  transform:skewX(0deg);
  transition-duration:.2s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  background:blue
  }
.main:hover {
transform: translateX(0);
}

.main:hover  .content {
  transform:skewX(10deg);
    }
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/ahamdan/pen/XWKdrrj